# Where should i start to live stream hololens to python server with webrtc?

Tags: python, c#, server, uwp, hololens

Recently i have been working on a project to stream Hololens video and audio to python server.
That is sending hololens video frame to python server and use python to do image processing.

On the Hololens i use unity as development platform, and i want to use webrtc (base on this repo [Mixed-reality webrtc](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WebRTC)).
I think i just know the concept of how webrtc working. But to the code, i just don't have idea where to start implementing this technique.
Hope anyone can give me come hint.

Comment: I had an experiment of streaming HoloLens to web browser via WebSocket instead.
https://youtu.be/1zh3VkwhIag
But I am struggling on how to get webcam view on Unity2019. The tool in my experiment called FMETP STREAM

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Python, but your Python server as a video receiver it should follow WebRTC specification. I believe there are reliable Python libraries related to WebRTC in Github.
For HoloLens side, since you mentioned that you are using the Unity for development, This [step-by-step guidance](http://%20https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WebRTC/manual/helloworld-unity-createproject.html) shows you how to implement Mixed-Reality WebRtc in Unity.

In short, we should add a [PeerConnection](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WebRTC/api/Microsoft.MixedReality.WebRTC.Unity.PeerConnection.html) component to a new GameObject in your scene. Then add the NodeDssSignaler component and configure it to connect to a Node-DSS server. Next, create a new game object and add a [WebcamSource](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WebRTC/api/Microsoft.MixedReality.WebRTC.Unity.WebcamSource.html) component, this component can generate video frames from a local video capture device (webcam), we need to config it. Finally, assign the Video Sender property of the PeerConnection component to the WebcanSource component created previously.